# How to TeX the following glyphs?

Tags: symbols

I'm making a complete list of glyphs typically used in research papers on arXiv which includes all the `cmr`, `cmmi`, `cmti`, `cmtt`, `cmcsc`, `cmex`, `cmbx`, `msam` and `msbm` glyphs and their TeX inputs.

I manually type the glyphs and use `dviasm` to verify that I have the right ones in the right locations. There are a few glyphs that can not be obtained for now.

Here are my questions:

1. How to obtain numbers and capitalized Greek letters for `cmmi`? If we use the math mode alone we obtain `cmr`.
2. What are glyphs `\fontfamily{cmsy}\fontencoding{OMS}\selectfont\char"36` and `\fontfamily{cmsy}\fontencoding{OMS}\selectfont\char"73`? The former isn't really a `/` while the latter isn't really an `\int`.
3. What are the glyphs `\fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"0C`  and `\fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"0D`?
4. What is the glyph  `\fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"47`? It is larger than both `\sqcup` and `\bigsqcup`.

P.S. Here is my current list of glyphs which is also available on my GitHub page: https://github.com/mathyingzhou/tex-encoding. The `cmr`, `cmsy` and `cmex` portions should be 100% correct. The `cmmi` portion should be correct in all glyphs other than numbers and capitalized Greek letters.

```
1.cmr\\
\noindent $\Gamma$ $\Delta$ $\Theta$ $\Lambda$ $\Xi$ $\Pi$ $\Sigma$ $\Upsilon$ $\Phi$ $\Psi$ $\Omega$ ff fi fl ffi ffl\\
\i\ \j\ \`{} \'{} \v{} \u{} \={} \r{} \c{} \ss\ \ae\ \oe\ \o\ \AE\ \OE\ \O\\\
\fontfamily{cmr}\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont\char"20\ ! \textquotedblright\ \#\ \$\ \%\ \&\ \textquoteright\ ( ) * + , - . /\\
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; \textexclamdown\ = \textquestiondown\ ?\\
@ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O\\
P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \textquotedblleft\ ] \^{} \.{} \\
\textquoteleft\ a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o\\
p q r s t u v w x y z \textendash\ \textemdash\ \H{} \~{} \"{}\\
2.cmsy\\
$-$ $\cdot$ $\times$ $*$ $\div$ $\diamond$ $\pm$ $\mp$ $\oplus$ $\ominus$ $\otimes$ $\oslash$ $\odot$ $\bigcirc$ $\circ$ $\bullet$\\
$\asymp$ $\equiv$ $\subseteq$ $\supseteq$ $\leq$ $\geq$ $\preceq$ $\succeq$ $\sim$ $\approx$ $\subset$ $\supset$ $\ll$ $\gg$ $\prec$ $\succ$\\
$\leftarrow$ $\rightarrow$ $\uparrow$ $\downarrow$ $\leftrightarrow$ $\nearrow$ $\searrow$ $\simeq$ $\Leftarrow$ $\Rightarrow$ $\Uparrow$ $\Downarrow$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\nwarrow$ $\swarrow$ $\propto$\\
$\prime$ $\infty$ $\in$ $\ni$ $\bigtriangleup$ $\bigtriangledown$ \fontfamily{cmsy}\fontencoding{OMS}\selectfont\char"36\  $\mapstochar$ $\forall$ $\exists$ $\neg$ $\emptyset$ $\Re$ $\Im$ $\top$ $\perp$\\
$\aleph$ $\mathcal{A}$ $\mathcal{B}$ $\mathcal{C}$ $\mathcal{D}$ $\mathcal{E}$ $\mathcal{F}$ $\mathcal{G}$ $\mathcal{H}$ $\mathcal{I}$ $\mathcal{J}$ $\mathcal{K}$ $\mathcal{L}$ $\mathcal{M}$ $\mathcal{N}$ $\mathcal{O}$\\
$\mathcal{P}$ $\mathcal{Q}$ $\mathcal{R}$ $\mathcal{S}$ $\mathcal{T}$ $\mathcal{U}$ $\mathcal{V}$ $\mathcal{W}$ $\mathcal{X}$ $\mathcal{Y}$ $\mathcal{Z}$ $\cup$ $\cap$ $\uplus$ $\wedge$ $\vee$\\
$\vdash$ $\dashv$ $\lfloor$ $\rfloor$ $\lceil$ $\rceil$ $\{$ $\}$ $\langle$ $\rangle$ $|$ $\parallel$ $\updownarrow$ $\Updownarrow$ $\backslash$ $\wr$\\
$\surd$ $\amalg$ $\nabla$ \fontfamily{cmsy}\fontencoding{OMS}\selectfont\char"73\  $\sqcup$ $\sqcap$ $\sqsubseteq$ $\sqsupseteq$ $\S$ $\dag$ $\ddag$ $\P$ $\clubsuit$ $\diamondsuit$ $\heartsuit$ $\spadesuit$\\ 
3.cmex\\
$\big($ $\big)$ $\big[$ $\big]$ $\big\lfloor$ $\big\rfloor$ $\big\lceil$ $\big\rceil$ $\big\{$ $\big\}$ $\big\langle$ $\big\rangle$ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"0C\  \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"0D\ $\big/$ $\big\backslash$\\
$\Big($ $\Big)$ $\bigg($ $\bigg)$ $\bigg[$ $\bigg]$ $\bigg\lfloor$ $\bigg\rfloor$ $\bigg\lceil$ $\bigg\rceil$ $\bigg\{$ $\bigg\}$ $\bigg\langle$ $\bigg\rangle$ $\bigg/$ $\bigg\backslash$\\
$\Bigg($ $\Bigg)$ $\Bigg[$ $\Bigg]$ $\Bigg\lfloor$ $\Bigg\rfloor$ $\Bigg\lceil$ $\Bigg\rceil$ $\Bigg\{$ $\Bigg\}$ $\Bigg\langle$ $\Bigg\rangle$ $\Bigg/$ $\Bigg\backslash$ $\Big/$ $\Big\backslash$\\
 \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"30\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"31\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"32\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"33\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"34\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"35\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"36\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"37\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"38\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"39\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"3A\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"3B\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"3C\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"3D\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"3E\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"3F\\\
\fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"40\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"41\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"42\ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"43\ $\Big\langle$ $\Big\rangle$ $\bigsqcup$ \fontfamily{cmex}\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"47\  $\oint$ $\displaystyle\oint$ $\bigodot$ $\displaystyle\bigodot$ $\bigoplus$ $\displaystyle\bigoplus$ $\bigotimes$ $\displaystyle\bigotimes$\\
$\sum$ $\prod$ $\int$ $\bigcup$ $\bigcap$ $\biguplus$ $\bigwedge$ $\bigvee$ $\displaystyle\sum$ $\displaystyle\prod$ $\displaystyle\int$ $\displaystyle\bigcup$ $\displaystyle\bigcap$ $\displaystyle\biguplus$ $\displaystyle\bigwedge$ $\displaystyle\bigvee$\\
$\coprod$ $\displaystyle\coprod$ $\widehat{}$ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"63\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"64\ $\widetilde{}$ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"66\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"67\ $\Big[$ $\Big]$ $\Big\lfloor$ $\Big\rfloor$ $\Big\lceil$ $\Big\rceil$ $\Big\{$ $\Big\}$\\
\fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"70\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"71\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"72\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"73\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"74\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"75\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"76\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"77\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"78\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"79\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"7A\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"7B\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"7C\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"7D\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"7E\ \fontencoding{OMX}\selectfont\char"7F\ \\
4.cmmi (need to change capitalized Greek alphabet, numbers)\\
\noindent $\Gamma$ $\Delta$ $\Theta$ $\Lambda$ $\Xi$ $\Pi$ $\Sigma$ $\Upsilon$ $\Phi$ $\Psi$ $\Omega$ $\alpha$ $\beta$ $\gamma$ $\delta$ $\epsilon$\\ 
$\zeta$ $\eta$ $\theta$ $\iota$ $\kappa$ $\lambda$ $\mu$ $\nu$ $\xi$ $\pi$ $\rho$ $\sigma$ $\tau$ $\upsilon$ $\phi$ $\chi$\\
$\psi$ $\omega$ $\varepsilon$ $\vartheta$ $\varpi$ $\varrho$ $\varsigma$ $\varphi$ $\leftharpoonup$ $\leftharpoondown$ $\rightharpoonup$ $\rightharpoondown$ $\lhook$ $\rhook$ $\triangleright$ $\triangleleft$\\
$0$ $1$ $2$ $3$ $4$ $5$ $6$ $7$ $8$ $9$ $.$ $,$ $<$ $/$ $>$ $\star$\\
$\partial$ $A$ $B$ $C$ $D$ $E$ $F$ $G$ $H$ $I$ $J$ $K$ $L$ $M$ $N$ $O$\\
$P$ $Q$ $R$ $S$ $T$ $U$ $V$ $W$ $X$ $Y$ $Z$ $\flat$ $\natural$ $\sharp$ $\smile$ $\frown$\\
$\ell$ $a$ $b$ $c$ $d$ $e$ $f$ $g$ $h$ $i$ $j$ $k$ $l$ $m$ $n$ $o$\\
$p$ $q$ $r$ $s$ $t$ $u$ $v$ $w$ $x$ $y$ $z$ $\imath$ $\jmath$ $\wp$ $\vec{}$ \t{}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the uppercase Greek letters in `cmmi` by `\mathnormal{\Gamma}` and so on. The slot numbers are the same as in `cmr`.

You can get information about the slots by looking at `fontmath.ltx`

Slot number `"36` in `cmsy` is for the `\not` glyph: it has zero width and the slash is meant to be centered over an equals sign after it.

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\not}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"36}
```

Slot number `"73` in `cmsy` is for a symbol called `\smallint`:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\smallint}{\mathop}{symbols}{"73}
```

Slot number `"0C` in `cmex` is for the repeating part of the extensible vertical bar:

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{|}{\mathord}{symbols}{"6A}{largesymbols}{"0C}
```

Slot number `"0D` in `cmex` is for the repeating part of the extensible vertical double bar:

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\Vert}{\mathord}{symbols}{"6B}{largesymbols}{"0D}
```

Slot number `"47` in `cmex` is `\bigsqcup` in the larger form, similarly to `\sum` that appears in two sizes at slots `"51` and `"5A`. When you type `\bigsqcup` you will get the glyph in slot `"47` if in display style (using font information stored in slot `"46`) and the glyph in slot `"46` otherwise. Such font information is obtained by `tftopl cmex10`

```
(CHARACTER O 106
   (CHARWD R 0.833336)
   (CHARDP R 1.000013)
   (NEXTLARGER O 107)
   )
(CHARACTER O 107
   (CHARWD R 1.1111145)
   (CHARHT R 0.100001)
   (CHARDP R 1.500012)
   )
```

You can see the `NEXTLARGER` instruction; slots are denoted in octal format and octal *`106* is hexadecimal `"46`

Comment: Really thanks! May I ask how to obtain TeX input info of glyphs for AMS and Euler fonts? Is http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/.cs.cmu.edu/local/tex/common/teTeX-3.0-distrib/share/texmf/tex/generic/encodings/msam.onm a good source?

Comment: @YingZhou I'd look in `amssymb.sty` and `eulervm.sty`